# Change title position in sweetalert popup and make inactive button sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I have a sweetlalert popup like this below

```js
Swal.fire({
        icon: "warning",
        title: 'By deleting this thing, you will delete all data related',
        text: "Are you sure you want to delete this  ?",
        input: 'checkbox',
        inputPlaceholder: 'I understand the consequenses',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        cancelButtonText: 'No',
        reverseButtons: true
    }).then(function(result){

    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```

Right now, the `text` position is before the `checkbox`.

I want to ask, how can I change the position so the `text` and `button confirm` in sweetalert position is after the checkbox and inactive, then after checkbox is checked, the `text` and `button` is become active ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by adding 3 css style rules in order to:

- change the check-box position (via flex-flow:row-reverse)
- the interaction/opacity
- and the row order (via flex-direction:column-reverse)

CSS:

```
.swal2-checkbox {
  /* change the checkbox position */
  flex-flow: row-reverse;
}

.swal2-actions {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.4
}

.swal2-content {
  /* change the row order */
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  display: flex;
}
```

in your javascript
you need to create a onclick event, which detects that the checkbox was clicked:

```
document.getElementById('swal2-checkbox').onclick=function(e){
  sel= document.querySelector(".swal2-actions")
  sel.style.pointerEvents='all'
  sel.style.opacity=1
}
```

```js
Swal.fire({
        icon: "warning",
        title: 'By deleting this thing, you will delete all data related',
        text: "Are you sure you want to delete this  ?",
        input: 'checkbox',
        inputPlaceholder: 'I understand the consequenses',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        cancelButtonText: 'No',
        reverseButtons: true
    }).then(function(result){

    })
    
document.getElementById('swal2-checkbox').onclick=function(e){
  sel = document.querySelector(".swal2-actions")
  sel.style.pointerEvents='all'
  sel.style.opacity=1
}
```

```css
.swal2-checkbox {
  flex-flow: row-reverse;
}

.swal2-actions {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.4
}

.swal2-content {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```

**note:** here is a very helpful ["cheatsheet" about CSS flexbox](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/#section-flex-direction) and here another [graphical guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Hi @Vickel, how to change checkbox position ? so text `Are you sure ...` is after the checkbox

Comment: @IkramShabri I have updated my answer, it was not clear to me in the 1st read of your question that you wanted those positions changed as well, hope that works for you now.